# How to pass a dict as a positional argument, not a keyword argument

Tags: python, dictionary, arguments, parameter-passing

I created a function (send_to_api) which takes three arguments. user_id and event_type take strings and event_properties takes a dictionary which I'm passing in as a positional argument. That's the format that is required by the external api. Here's a simplified version of the function:

```
def send_to_api(user_id, event_type, *args):

    event_args = {"user_id": user_id,
              "event_type": event_type,
              "event_properties": args}

    data = json.dumps(event_args)
    r = requests.post(url=url, data=data)
```

In a different place, the function gets called like this:

```
event_properties = {"property_1": "a", "property_whatever": "b"}

send_to_api("my_user_id", "my_event", event_properties)
```

After familiarizing myself with *args and **kwargs I still seem to be doing something wrong because the event_properties dict doesn't get passed through.

I think it's because I'm trying to pass a dictionary as a positional argument, could that be the reason? Or any other pointer as to where things are going wrong here?

Comment: Change `*args` to `args`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To better understanding you can just to debug your **send_to_api** function.
But in short:

1. *args is used to send a non-keyworded variable length argument list to the function

   ```
   def send_to_api(param1, param2, *args):
       print(param1, param2, args)
   ```

If you call then your function and pass after param1, param2 any numbers of positional arguments you can access them inside function in *args* tuple.
So in your question example your dict is inside *args* variable.

```
    send_to_api(1,2, {"a":1, "b":2})
    ...
    1 2 ({'a': 1, 'b': 2},)
```

And you can access it as **args[0]**, so your code might looks like:

```
    def send_to_api(user_id, event_type, *args):
        event_args = {"user_id": user_id,
                      "event_type": event_type,
                      "event_properties": args[0]}
```

But probably its better if you can change signature to smth like that:

```
    def send_to_api(user_id, event_type, event_properties, *args):
        event_args = {"user_id": user_id,
                      "event_type": event_type,
                      "event_properties": event_properties}
```

As for me it much more cleaner ;)

If you need to handle any numbers of positional arguments - use *args in function definition, then you can access them in **args** tuple inside function.

If you need to handle any numbers of keyworded arguments - use **kwargs in function definition, then inside function you can access them in kwargs dictionary.

so for example:

```
def send_to_api(arg1, *args, **kwargs):
    print(arg1, args, kwargs)
```

you can then call function with:

```
 send_to_api(1, 2 , key1=1, key2=2)
```

it will print:

```
 1 (2,) {'key1': 1, 'key2': 2}
```

so you can see that **args** is a tuple (2,); **kwargs** is a dictionary {'key1': 1, 'key2': 2}

Also you can pass kwargs to the function as a dictionary with unpack operator:

```
  send_to_api(1, 2, **{'key1': 1, 'key2': 2})
```

it will print the same:

```
   1 (2,) {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
```

So dictionary {'key1': 1, 'key2': 2} was unpacked with ** operator to key1=1, key2=2 keyword arguments and available inside your function in kwargs dict.

There no magic, just try to play in python interactive console.

Answer (score 0):

with one `*` it will be tuple, but with two `**` will be dictionary

```
def send_to_api(user_id, event_type, **args):
...
...
send_to_api("my_user_id", "my_event", **event_properties)
```

some useful [docs](http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/args_and_kwargs.html)

**Output**

```
{
 "user_id": "my_user_id", 
 "event_type": "my_event", 
 "event_properties": {
                       "property_1": "a", 
                       "property_whatever": "b"
                      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use dict unpacking like this:

```
send_to_api("my_user_id", "my_event", **event_properties)
```

Read more about this [here](http://send_to_api(%22my_user_id%22,%20%22my_event%22,%20event_properties)).

Answer (score 0):

*args and **kwargs are designed to enable passing variable number of arguments to a function. Before using them, you need to know whether you need `keyworded` argument or `non-keyworded` arguments.

In your case, you are using keyword based argument, so you need to change it to `**kwargs`

```
def test_arg_kwargs(arg1, arg2, **kwargs):
    print("arg1:", arg1)
    print("arg2:", arg2)
    print("arg3:", kwargs)


event_properties = {"property_1": "a", "property_whatever": "b"}

test_arg_kwargs('arg1', 'arg2', **event_properties)
```

output:

```
arg1: arg1
arg2: arg2
arg3: {'property_1': 'a', 'property_whatever': 'b'}
```